# Which are the Betz's limits for marine devices such as wave energy converters?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, energy-efficiency, water-resources, renewable-energy

Nowadays, climate change is a relevant topic to reflect on the uses of renewable energies, such as the Sun, wind, oceans, tides, etc. Engineers are trying to design devices to extract the most power from wind turbines, waves, tides, etc. However, Betz’s law says a wind turbine can not capture more than 16/27 (59.3%) of the kinetic energy ([Wikipedia, 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betz%27s_law#:%7E:text=Betz%27s%20law%20shows%20that%20as,to%20a%20maximum%20of%2059.3%25.)). Do you know Betz’s limits for marine devices such as wave energy converters (WEC) and tidal devices?

Comment: Do some research outside of wikipedia: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/238184620_Beating_Betz_Energy_Extraction_Limits_in_a_Constrained_Flow_Field SO much more to read and understand...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a similar analysis can be and has been performed for power extraction from water waves. I can't remember the details right now but rest assured it is the first derivation in a textbook analysis of wave power.